# Publish/Expose ip of qemu running inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running an application on QEMU which is running inside a docker container.
The target ip is used to access the application:

```
target_ip=IPv4Address('192.168.32.20')
```

With docker compose, I would like to access the application on Host as well as on other containers running on the network.

Is there a way I can map the ip?

Comment: Which ways are open to you on the qemu end depends on which qemu network backend you're using.

Comment: Did you set up with `-net tap`? `-net vde`? The default `-net user`? Something else?

Comment: ...really there are two _separate_ problems here, qemu configuration and Docker configuration, and in an ideal world you'd handle each of them separately (confirming that your networking is right inside qemu when running the same setup without Docker; testing that your networking is correct inside Docker when running a service other than qemu) instead of getting into a situation where you have to set them _both_ up correctly at the same time and don't have an easy way to determine which of the two is the cause of a given problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: do you mean the qemu  ifup network setup? it was done with tap